# How to pass multiple commands to docker-compose.uffizzi.yml

Tags: docker-compose, docker-command

I need to pass the next command to my service in docker-compose.uffizzi.yml

`bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate db:seed && bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`

According to this doc: https://docs.uffizzi.com/references/compose-spec/#command

command can be passed as usual or converted to an array of strings.

But when I use it in such way I get the next error:

`Error: failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate db:seed && bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

But if I use only one of the commands

`bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate db:seed`

or only

`bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`

it works fine. But I need both of them in my service command.

Do you have any ideas how to write this command in a right way?)

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is to use command this way:

```
command: ["bash", "-c", "bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate db:seed && bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000"]
```